# how to write API credentials in admin login page?

Tags: admin, api, credentials

I wrote a custom module to do the API cron job. However I included all the API path and access token inside the cron job. I would like to have in admin page for user to store their API path credentials in admin page. Is there any tutorials that I can follow steps to do that? I did google for the solution, however I couldn't find any good example. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Yes Its simple create a configuration for your module. etc/adminhtml/system.xml create your configuration whatever you need add the input elements. For retrieving you need to create a helper class.
Everything is in the following link.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-system-xml-configuration-magento-2.html